# Strange orchestration behaviour of a Docker Swarm manager - pile of containers

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

For some unknown reason, the manager host which gets the command to launch a stack, tries to pile up all the containers on itself; other worker/manager hosts stay unemploed.

Unfortunately there are no log entries for that.

Has anybody observed this behaviour already with Docker CE as well?

Answer (score 1):

I would check that all nodes are active and ready with command

```
docker node ls
```

With

```
docker swarm leave
```

and

```
docker swarm join \
--token <SWMTKN token> \
<manager private IP>
```

you may rejoin malfunctioning node.